# Accessing wcf data contracts in client projects

Tags: service, wcf-data-services

I have a wcf service which has a data contract say 
1. Wcf service which has a data contract class called Rundata
2. Client WPF application which has multiple below listed projects under one solution
    - wcfservice accessor
.   - data analyser
.   - data displayer
Now I made a service references in "wcfservice accessor" and I received the rundata object from the wcf service. Now my question is : 
1. How can I make the "data analyser" and "data displayer" project to understand this rundata object since only "wcfservice accessor" alone has the service reference.

Comment: Why do you want other projects `data analyser` to have access to the proxy object? If really needed then why don't you create one in each project referring the service?

Comment: I need it in all projects. Why should other classes to know the about services proxy. I wanted to split the wcf communication to that(wcfservice accessor) project alone

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if your architecture is not allowing to 'see' the classes generated in the service reference. usually you need DTO class, DTO stands for "data transformation object" or "data transport object" it matters the case. So in the "data analyser" project is your business logic it need to have a reference to "wcfservice accessor" and the "data displayer" have a reference to "data analyser". So from "data analyser" to "data displayer" you can use so called DTO object.